# ZigBee Network Configuration

Tags: zigbee

I want to establish a network of four ZigBee RF modules connected to Arduino microcontrollers which can intercommunicate some data between each other. Data may be some randomly generated data by microcontrollers or may be some sensor data. Network in which each node can receive and send data to each node of the network.

For this, how should I configure my ZigBee RF modules?

Answer (score 0):

Take one XBEE baseboard, connect it to the computer using USB and use XCTU software on windows to configure each of them individually one by one.